# date time error in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I got the following error when trying to retrieve the data to the datetime picker control when clicking on the datagridview row.

```
Dim i as byte
 i = tblView.CurrentRow.Index

 txtEnterDate.Text = tblView.Item(2, i).Value
 txtPubYear.Text = tblView.Item(3, i).Value
```

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: What are the values at 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as through there's a DateTimePicker involved, and there's a validated date already in `Item(2,i)`

Try this:

```
 txtEnterDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(tblView.Item(2, i).Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting suggests that the tblView Item collection has invalid data. Without seeing more code, its hard to tell what's going on. I would suggest setting a breakpoint on the offending line and using the Immediate window to determine why your array collection is empty.

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly good suggestion for how to go about debugging this code.  Given the information we have anything else is a guess anyway.